# How to convert Base64 string to PNG (currently using Jimp)?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, base64, jimp

I'm currently creating a real-time chat application. This is a web application that uses `node.js` for the backend and uses `socket.io` to connect back and forth.

Currently, I'm working on creating user profiles with profile pictures. These profile pictures will be stored in a folder called `images/profiles/`. The file will be named by the user's `id`. For example: user with the `id` 1 will have their profile pictures stored in `images/profiles/1.png`. Very self-explanatory.

When the user submits the form to change their profile picture, the browser JavaScript will get the image, and send it to the server:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm)

function handleForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop page from reloading

  let profilePicture; // set variable for profile picture
  let profilePictureInput = document.getElementById('profilePictureInput'); // get image input

  const files = profilePictureInput.files[0]; // get input's files

  if (files) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader(); // initialize file reader

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      profilePicture = this.result; // put result into variable

      socket.emit("request-name", {
        profilePicture: profilePicture,
        id: userID,
      }); // send result, along with user id, to server
  }
}
```

I've commented most of the code so it's easy to follow. The server then gets this information. With this information, the server is supposed to convert the sent image to a `png` format (I can do whatever format, but it has to be the same format for all images). I am currently using the `jimp` library to do this task, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
const jimp = require('jimp'); // initialize Jimp

socket.on('request-name', (data) => { // when request has been received
  // read the buffer from image (I'm not 100% sure what Buffer.from() does, but I saw this online)
  jimp.read(Buffer.from(data.profilePicture), function (error, image) {
    if (error) throw error; // throw error if there is one

    image.write(`images/profiles/${data.id}.png`); // write image to designated place
  }
});
```

The error I get:

```
Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>
```

I've scoured the internet for answers but was unable to find any. I am available to use another library if this helps. I can also change the file format (`.png` to `.jpg` or `.jpeg`, if needed; it just needs to be consistent with all files). The only things I cannot change are the use of JavaScript/`Node.js` and `socket.io` to send the information to the server.

Thank you in advance. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting the data URI as a string, then you can construct a buffer with it and then use the built in `fs` to write the file. Make sure the relative path is accurate.

```js
socket.on('request-name', data => {
  const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(data.profilePicture, 'base64');
  fs.writeFile(`images/profiles/${data.id}.png`, imgBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm getting this error when I use this code: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`. This is from the `fs.writeFile('filePath', imgBuffer);` line of code.

Comment: @IPSDSILVA either use `writeFileSync` or pass in `()=>null` as the last parameter --- if you have a specific task to run after saving the file, you can do so within the callback